# ASP.NET MVC applicationt - using SharePoint 2013 as a document repository

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-foundation, asp.net, document

We are developing an asp.net mvc application with a lot of custom data but want to use sharepoint 2013 for document repository. What is the best way to move ahead? Is Sharepoint 2013 foundation sufficent for our requirements?

Answer (score 4):

It depends on your needs of course. But if only for storage and security, foundation should be enough.

You can use the managed client object model for communication with SharePoint from your MVC app: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee857094(v=office.14).aspx

OR, Since you use 2013:

You could add a SharePoint Provider Hosted App to your MVC Solution (Where your MVC app will really be the Provider hosted app), and create lists and libraries in that SharePoint App web, for storage. http://blogs.msdn.com/b/bspann/archive/2013/01/19/asp-net-mvc-based-apps-for-sharepoint-2013-on-premises.aspx

another great walk-through: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/695161/Walkthrough-Creating-a-O365-SharePoint-2013-App-wi

Comment: +1, great answer!

Comment: It seems that these links require running a sharepoint server too. Is there a way to use the sharepoint code as a backing without having to run it through an existing sharepoint server?